# XSLT format XML that can have different children nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML that I'm trying to transform:

```
    <Loop20>
          <Loop21>
            <CLP>
              <F1028>0000003797</F1028>
              <F1029>1</F1029>
              <F782_1>100</F782_1>
              <F782_2>75</F782_2>
              <F782_3>45</F782_3>
              <F1032>MB</F1032>
              <F127>0000003797</F127>
              <F1331>11</F1331>
            </CLP>
            <NM1>
              <F98_1>QC</F98_1>
              <F1065>1</F1065>
              <F1035_1>Hassle</F1035_1>
              <F1036>Elizabeth</F1036>
              <F66>MI</F66>
              <F67>0000000001-01</F67>
            </NM1>
            <NM1>
              <F98_1>82</F98_1>
              <F1065>1</F1065>
              <F1035_1>Kifle</F1035_1>
              <F1036>Getahun</F1036>
              <F66>XX</F66>
              <F67>1366645236</F67>
            </NM1>
         <Loop21>
    <Loop20>
```

My goal is to have the output formatted:

CLP`*`0000003797`*`1`*`100`*`75`*`45`*`MB`*`0000003797`*`11
NM1`*`QC`*`1`*`Hassle`*`Elizabeth`*`MI`*`0000000001-01
NM1`*`82`*`1`*`Kifle`*`Getahun`*`XX`*`1366645236

My question is there an easy way to do this without nesting a bunch of for-each statements? I have tried the following however it can't handle when there are multiple children.

```
       <xsl:for-each select="/*">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />*
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                      *<xsl:value-of select="." />*
                    </xsl:for-each>     
                </td>           
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output (reducing the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem would also be welcome - see: [mcve]. In addition, your title says "sorting" but the question does not seem to have anything to do with sorting.

Comment: You might want to simplify the sample data but then show us and explain us exactly which result you want for that sample. In general you can use recursive push style processing and also rely on built-in templates output text nodes anyway so `<xsl:template match="*[*]"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: The output you show contradicts your attempt: you are trying to produce an HTML table, not delimited text. Which one should it be?

Comment: Sorry, you can't delimit text then display in a table?

Comment: I am afraid you are missing my point. If you want to produce an HTML table, then show the exact HTML code you expect to get as the result of transforming the input example. If you want to have delimited text within that table, then show it that way. Right now you are showing delimited text and ONLY delimited text. Which means I don't know what is the result you're trying to produce. Which means I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The result you show can be produced easily by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whether this fits all your possible inputs is unclear.