# XSLT for-each insert text before each iteration

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<CAS>
  <F1033>PR</F1033>
  <F1034_1>3</F1034_1>
  <F782_1>45</F782_1>
</CAS>
<CAS>
   <F1033>CO</F1033>
   <F1034_1>45</F1034_1>
   <F782_1>99.54</F782_1>
 </CAS>
```

I want to loop through the xml in order to produce:

CAS`*`PR`*`3`*`45

CAS`*`CO`*`45`*`99.54

I have tried the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//CAS/*">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:text>CAS*</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
    <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it outputs:

CAS`*`PR`*`3`*`45`*`CO`*`45`*`99.54

How do I insert the CAS* and a line break at the beginning of each iteration to produce my desired results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSLT-1.0 code which uses two `xsl:for-each` loops and inserts the *line-break* after the first loop:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="CAS">
            <xsl:text>CAS*</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>        

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
CAS*PR*3*45
CAS*CO*45*99.54
```

Comment: You could simplify this by making the text only `CAS` and placing the `*` separator **before** each child element. Then you won't need the `xsl:if` part. But I already gave this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466041/3016153). For some reason OP ignored this and posted essentially the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 or 3 you can use the rather compact

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="CAS">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(), *" separator="*"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```